# Scrapy No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: scrapy, python-import, pandas.excelwriter

I got the data I wished to scrape from the url, however when it came to importing data to Excel using ExcelWriter I got the following error:

```
[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
import time
import json
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException,\
    ElementClickInterceptedException,\
    NoSuchElementException,\
    ElementNotInteractableException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from crypto_prices.items import CryptoPricesItem

class TvCryptoPricesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tv_crypto_prices'
    allowed_domains = ['tradingview.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-all/']

    def parse(self, response):
        #Set driver
        global driver
        driver = ChromeDriver()
        driver.get(response.url)

        #Set currency
        currency = "BTC"
        self.set_currency(currency)

        #Accept all
        time.sleep(4)
        self.accept_all()

        #Crypto prices
        source = self.fetch_data()
        data = source[1]

        #Save as json
        categories = self.get_categories()
        categories_list = self.get_categories_list(categories)
        for idx, category in enumerate(categories_list):
            self.save_as_json(category, data[idx])

    #Click "Accept all" button for preferences
    def accept_all(self):
        try:
            promtpw = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='item-x59qvYIc']")
            promtpw = promtpw.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                           "//button[@class='acceptAll-ofWyKNKk button-KXqj4Lf5 size-xsmall-KXqj4Lf5 color-brand-KXqj4Lf5 variant-primary-KXqj4Lf5']").click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass
        except ElementNotInteractableException:
            pass

    #Toggle button
    def toggle_button(self):
        toggle_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='checkbox']")
        toggle_button.click()
    
    #Set currency
    def set_currency(self, currency):
        active_currency = self.get_active_currency()
        if active_currency != currency:
            self.toggle_button()
        else:
            pass

    #Get active currency
    def get_active_currency(self):
        active_currency = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'modeTitleActive-AXg2YMF0')]").text
        return active_currency

    #Get list of category objects
    def get_categories(self):
        categories = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class, 'item-x59qvYIc')]")
        return categories

    #Get categories list
    def get_categories_list(categories_objs):
        categories_list = []
        for category in categories:
            append_category_text = categories_list.append(category.text)
        return categories_list

    #Get crypto prices
    def fetch_data(self):
        data = []
        categories = self.get_categories()
        for category in categories:
            time.sleep(2)
            category.click()
            time.sleep(2)
            append_data = data.append(pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[1])
        self.quit_driver()
        return data

    #Save as json
    def save_as_json(self, category, data):
        file = f"json/tv_crypto_prices_{category}.json"
        file_title = category
        data.to_json(file, orient="records", indent=2)

    #Quit driver
    def quit_driver(self):
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()


#Driver
def ChromeDriver():
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.headless = False
    service = ChromeService("C:\Python39\chromedriver.exe")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)
    return driver
```

I did some research and found out it might have been that there's nothing listening on given port and/or something to do with the scrapy extension telnet but didn't find much of a solution as to how to fix it. I tried the code on jupyter and everything worked fine. Everything was done on Windows 10. Does anyone know how to fix the problem?

Comment: Please include a snippet containing your code